# Is there a simple way to transfer a constant pointer into a function?

Tags: c++

Since if there is a function like this:

```
void AAA (int i);
```

I can pass the number 5 into the function easily as:

```
AAA (5);
```

If the function spec like this:

```
void BBB (int* pi)
```

Is there a simple way to pass the number 5 into the function easily, too?

Like this:

```
BBB (&5)
```

I know `BBB (&5)` is wrong and cannot pass the compiler,
but I don't want to write as:

```
int i = 5;
```

BBB (&i);

How to modify `BBB (&5)` into a correct form?

Comment: How do you know `BBB` won't modify what `pi` points to (e.g., `*pi = 42;`)?  That's why you need the temporary.

Comment: Read about [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

Comment: You can't. `void BBB (int* pi)` requires a pointer to an int, which means that the contents of `pi` can be modified, `5` is a constant, and you can't modify a constant when passed into a function. You can't make a constant a pointer, because it's not a pointer.

Comment: *"I don't want to write as..."* - then you shouldn't have written `BBB` as  `BBB(int *pi)` in the first place. From what little you've shown, either an overload or reference solution would work. this is, after all, C++.

Comment: I see the point.

Thanks to everyone.